# DBNULL assignment to a "NUMBER" field in Oracle

Tags: asp.net, oracle11g

I am trying to convert an ASP.Net application that was using SQL Server to one using Oracle 11g. In ine of the table, there is a field defined as Number(10,0). It is also a foreign key so 0 is invalid value for this field. In DAL, I check like this:

```
oraCmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("MPID", OracleDbType.Int32));
oraCmd.Parameters["MPID"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;                 

if (NewCustomer.MPId == 0)
    oraCmd.Parameters["MPID"].Value = DBNull.Value;
else
    oraCmd.Parameters["MPID"].Value = NewCustomer.MPID;
```

When MPId is zero, it fails to add the record saying "Value does not fall within the expected range".

Comment: Is `MPID` in your database nullable?

Comment: Yes it is is defined as nullable.